# Looking for a well written inifite scroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Does anyone have some good recommendations for an infinite scroll plugin(like twitter) Where you scroll down and more content will be dynamically loaded.

I am looking to use jquery, angular or javascript.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For infinite scrolling you should do ajax to load more content in your page each time when scroller hits the bottom of the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
          angular.element("#yourControllerId").scope().loadMore();

      }
  });

  // angularJs code
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
    // do ajax
  }
```